# implementing search not working in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

Working on a web api for our mobile app, and we can't seem to get our search method to work.
When we try to call from the api we get the following result for our search method

```
 <Error>
 <Message>
 No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://hippokros-     api.azurewebsites.net/api/Recommends/GetCardRecommendsByFriendId/100000097477513'.
 </Message>
 <MessageDetail>
 No action was found on the controller 'Recommends' that matches the request.
 </MessageDetail>
 </Error>
```

We get a 502 HTTP request in Fiddler, but when we call GetRecommends/1 and pass in the id we get results.

Are controller code is short so i'll just display all of it

```
 public class RecommendsController : ApiController
{
    private mtgServiceEntities db = new mtgServiceEntities();

    // GET: api/Recommends
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Recommend> GetRecommends()
    {
        return db.Recommends;
    }

    // GET: api/Recommends/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Recommend))]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRecommend(int id)
    {
        Recommend recommend = db.Recommends.Find(id);

        if (recommend == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(recommend);
    }

    // GET: api/Recommends/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Recommend))]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRecommend(string cardname)
    {
        List<Recommend> recommend = db.Recommends.Where(x => x.card_name == cardname).ToList();

        if (recommend == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(recommend);
    }

    //GET: api/Recommend/Search/cardname
    [ResponseType(typeof(Recommend))]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetFriendRecommendsByCardName(string cardname)
    {
        List<Recommend> recommends = db.Recommends.Where(x => x.card_name == cardname).ToList();
        return Ok(recommends);
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(Recommend))]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCardRecommendsByFriendId(string friendId)
    {
        List<Recommend> recommends = db.Recommends.Where(x => x.facebookId == friendId).ToList();
        return Ok(recommends);
    }

    // PUT: api/Recommends/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutRecommend(int id, Recommend recommend)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != recommend.ID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(recommend).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!RecommendExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Recommends
    [ResponseType(typeof(Recommend))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostRecommend(Recommend recommend)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Recommends.Add(recommend);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (RecommendExists(recommend.ID))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = recommend.ID }, recommend);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Recommends/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Recommend))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteRecommend(int id)
    {
        Recommend recommend = db.Recommends.Find(id);
        if (recommend == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Recommends.Remove(recommend);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(recommend);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool RecommendExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Recommends.Count(e => e.ID == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

and our routing in the webapiconfig file is as follows

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

We're not sure what setting or configuration we have wrong, but basically it's telling us there's nothing there when we know we have the right URL and we're using https to call it.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use attribute routing because I can easily see what is mapped to what:) I recommend to read [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) to better understand the Web API Attribute routing.

To match your address you can try the following code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/recommends")]
public class RecommendsController : ApiController
{
    ...

    Route("GetCardRecommendsByFriendId/{friendId}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Recommend))]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCardRecommendsByFriendId(string friendId)
    {
       List<Recommend> recommends = db.Recommends.Where(x => x.facebookId == friendId).ToList();
       return Ok(recommends);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I still get the following error when trying to retrieve the data

Comment: <Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://hippokros-api.azurewebsites.net/api/Recommends/GetCardRecommendsByFriendId/100000097477513'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'Recommends' that matches the name 'GetCardRecommendsByFriendId'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>

Comment: I enabled MapMvcAttributeRoutes in routingconfig and used your code and tried to hit it but still same old error.  Is there a configuration i'm missing in web.config that would make it working?